Issue Integrating Adyen SDK Android Components with SessionComponentCallback
I am currently working on integrating the Adyen SDK Android Components into our application, but I've encountered an issue with implementing the SessionComponentCallback. Despite following the documentation, I am unable to get the callback to work correctly.
Below is the relevant portion of my implementation:
val paymentMethod = checkoutSession?.getPaymentMethod(PaymentMethodTypes.GOOGLE_PAY)

val cardComponent = CardComponent.PROVIDER.get(
    requireActivity(),
    checkoutSession,
    paymentMethod,
    object : SessionComponentCallback<> {

        override fun onFinished(result: SessionPaymentResult) {
            // The payment finishes with a result.
        }

        override fun onAction(action: Action) {
            // An additional action needs to be handled. Forward the action to the Component.
            //cardComponent.handleAction(action, activity)
        }

        override fun onError(componentError: ComponentError) {
            // The Component encounters an error.
        }
    },
    null,
)
binding.adyenView.attach(cardComponent, requireActivity())

I don't know what to put in SessionComponentCallback<>.
